# Change default language of the Angular datatable

Tags: angular, datatable

I've successfully implemented the [Angular DataTable](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/getting-started) in my application. The only problem is that I can't figure out how to configure my own language settings for the datatable. The only threads who covers this topic is in AngularJS.

[datatable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cn9tG.png)

E.g. "Show X entries" -> "Viser X rader", "Search" -> "Søk", "Previous" -> "Forrige", etc ...

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you want change the language of what? paginator?

Comment: I want to change the language of the entire datatable. E.g. "Show X entires" -> "Vis 10 rader", "Search" -> "Søk", "Previous" -> "Forrige", "Next" -> "Neste", etc...

Comment: Added a screenshot of the datatable.

Comment: Tusen takk for hjelpen ;)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36849610/datatables-change-interface-language) answer, I finally figured it out.

```
export const norwegian = {
  'emptyTable': 'Ingen data tilgjengelig i tabellen',
  'info': 'Viser side _PAGE_ av _PAGES_',
  'infoEmpty': 'Viser 0 til 0 av 0 linjer',
  'infoFiltered': '(filtrert fra _MAX_ totalt antall linjer)',
  'infoPostFix': '',
  'infoThousands': ' ',
  'loadingRecords': 'Laster...',
  'lengthMenu': 'Viser _MENU_ rader',
  'processing': 'Laster...',
  'search': 'S&oslash;k:',
  'url': '',
  'zeroRecords': 'Ingen rader matcher s&oslash;ket',
  'paginate': {
    'first': '&laquo;&laquo;',
    'previous': '&laquo;',
    'next': '&raquo;',
    'last': '&raquo;&raquo;'
  },
  'aria': {
    'sortAscending': ': aktiver for å sortere kolonnen stigende',
    'sortDescending': ': aktiver for å sortere kolonnen synkende'
  }
};
```

Import the file in your component and set the dtOptions like this:

```
this.dtOptions = {
      pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      language: norwegian
    };
```